# Python to_json function not converting DataFrame to Json in proper format for Date Field

Tags: python, pandas, data-conversion, to-json

I am facing a problem in receiving correct date formatted data from the CSV using to_json function of pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\shubham\\Desktop\\Output\\MasterData.csv")
df1 = df.to_json(orient='records')
print(df1)
```

Current Output:-

```
[{"invoiceDate":"18\/08\/2019","amount":1140.87}]
```

I am expecting Output:- "invoiceDate":"18/08/2019"

I already tried to_json arguments:- `date_format = "iso" double_precision = 10, force_ascii = True, date_unit = "ms", default_handler = None)`, and replace is also not working `(df.replace("/",""))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the replace function in the `data-frame` to replace forward slash as per my need.

The following code helped me to archive my desire output.

```
df1 = df.to_json(orient='records',lines=True).replace('\\r\\n', " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Create dictionary and write to file with [`json.dump`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{"invoiceDate":"18/08/2019","amount":1140.87}])
print (df)
  invoiceDate   amount
0  18/08/2019  1140.87


import json
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(df.to_dict(orient='records'), f)

#[{"invoiceDate": "18/08/2019", "amount": 1140.87}]
```